# Complex Array Task

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve a complex problem with array in java .

It starts with a String.

```
String text = "I am the best Programmmer in the world the best";

String [] arraytext = text.split("");
```

the next was to iterate the array and check for records

```
for (String array1 : arraytext) {
       System.out.println(array1);
            }
```

This works and I have my array

The problem I have now is to check the array for a record and get the index of the array.

i mean

```
for (String array1 : arraytext) {
    if (array1.equalsIgnoreCase("best")){
            // get the index of this array

            }
        }
```

I need to get d index of that array . its quite complex because I actually need the index of the second instance of the best.

and get the result of this index out of the for loop.

Will really appreciate any help

Comment: So basically you just want the index of the second instance?

Comment: you need to pass a string to the split() method with a delimiter (that is where the string will be split)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is to split your string correctly, you probably want to split on either `" "` or use regex to check for a more extensive whitespace list.

Then all you need to do is create a method to do the search looking something like this:

```
int findIndex(String str, int start, String[] array) {
   for (int i=start;i<array.length;i++) {
      if (array[i].equals(str)) {
          return i;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Then to get the first you do:

```
index = findIndex("test", 0, array);
```

For the second you do:

```
index = findIndex("test", index+1, array);
```

If nothing is found then index will be -1.

Answer (score 0):

What about to change the for loop in

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraytext.length ; i++){
    if(arrayText[i].equalsIgnoreCase("best"))
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Thankss this prints out the result of the index 3 and 9 , now please what I need is the result of this 9 which is the second instance of the best. I need this 9 out side the for loop

Comment: you can cast a new variable BEFORE the for loop something like `int index = 0;` then the for loop and then instead of `System.out.println(i)` you can write `index = i;` and then when you're outside the loop you can access to i which contains the index of the searched word

Answer (score 0):

Java's Foreach syntax is just syntactical sugar around a `for` loop.  If you want to find the last matching element, the easiest thing to do is to manually write the `for` loop yourself, but iterate backwards.  Something like this.

```
for (int i = arraytext.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (arraytext[i].equalsIgnoreCase("best"))
    {
        // i is the array index you're looking for, do something with it
        break; // or return if this is a method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayUtils:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
int index = ArrayUtils.lastIndexOf(arraytext, "best");
```